# Understanding mutable vectors and how to modify them in Haskell

Tags: haskell, vector, monads

I'm looking at some of the source codes from [JuicyPixels](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-3.3.5/docs/src/Codec.Picture.Types.html), and the mutable vector is confusing me. In the function `generateMutableImage` at line 808 which is

```
generateMutableImage :: forall m px. (Pixel px, PrimMonad m)
                     => (Int -> Int -> px)  -- ^ Generating function, with `x` and `y` params.
                     -> Int        -- ^ Width in pixels
                     -> Int        -- ^ Height in pixels
                     -> m (MutableImage (PrimState m) px)
{-# INLINE generateMutableImage #-}
generateMutableImage f w h = MutableImage w h `liftM` generated where
  compCount = componentCount (undefined :: px)

  generated = do
    arr <- M.new (w * h * compCount)
    let lineGenerator _ !y | y >= h = return ()
        lineGenerator !lineIdx y = column lineIdx 0
          where column !idx !x | x >= w = lineGenerator idx $ y + 1
                column idx x = do
                    unsafeWritePixel arr idx $ f x y
                    column (idx + compCount) $ x + 1
    lineGenerator 0 0
    return arr
```

I thought the `generated` is of type `m (Data.Vector.Storable.Mutable.STVector)` and understood how it is declared, but I don't know how it is modified.

I know the `unsafeWritePixel` is the one responsible for this, but how's it connected with the `(PrimMonad m) => m` monad?

Also, what does the `!` of `!y` mean? Are these some magical operators or notations?

Comment: `!` in `!y` is a *bang pattern*: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/bang-patterns.html

Comment: A typical implementation of `unsafeWritePixel` will use [this `unsafeWrite`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.2.0/docs/Data-Vector-Storable-Mutable.html#v:unsafeWrite). This is the connection between `unsafeWritePixel` and `PrimMonad`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet

```
let lineGenerator _ !y | y >= h = return ()
    lineGenerator !lineIdx y = column lineIdx 0
      where column !idx !x | x >= w = lineGenerator idx $ y + 1
            column idx x = do
                unsafeWritePixel arr idx $ f x y
                column (idx + compCount) $ x + 1
lineGenerator 0 0
```

is a sort-of loop, writing image data in the vector.

This is realized by defining a recursive function `lineGenerator` and then invoking it with the starting values in `lineGenerator 0 0`. The first argument is the index, which refers to the position is the vector we are writing, and is frequently incremented during the recursion. The second argument represent the `y` coordinate of the image. Both start at `0`.

Let's comment in detail, line-by-line:

```
let lineGenerator _ !y | y >= h = return ()
```

If the current `y` is `>=` than the height, we stop the loop.

```
    lineGenerator !lineIdx y = column lineIdx 0
```

Otherwise, fill a row. Let `x` start from `0`.

```
      where column !idx !x | x >= w = lineGenerator idx $ y + 1
```

If `x` has reached the width `w`, we filled the line, so move on to the next by incrementing `y`.

```
            column idx x = do
```

Otherwise, we need to write a pixel in the current line.

```
                unsafeWritePixel arr idx $ f x y
```

Write it at the current index, and use `f x y` to compute image data according to the current values of `x` and `y`.

```
                column (idx + compCount) $ x + 1
```

Then, move to the next pixel, advancing both the `x` coordinate and the vector index (so that we won't overwrite the pixel we just wrote).

Everything seems to be performed inside the `m` monad, which is needed since we need to mutate the vector.

You can safely ignore the `!` in `!y` and in the other variables. These are called "bang patterns", and are used here as an optimization, to ensure that numeric values like `x+1` are immediately computed and not kept around unevaluated. Haskell is lazy by default and won't compute anything unless it's needed right now, but this might affect performance so sometimes programmers disable laziness manually using bang patterns. Again, when reading code you can pretend these `!` bangs don't exist.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I gathered that I can simply use the ```unsafeWritePixel``` without worrying how the vector is actually updated, maybe in the ```(PrimMonad m) => m```?

Comment: @Chien I don't understand what you are trying to do, but yes, you can use `unsafeWritePixel` on any valid `index` to update a pixel. Be very careful to provide a valid `index`, in the range of the vector, since otherwise the program behavior is undefined (that's why it's called "unsafe").

Comment: This is clear to me now, thank you for the help!